# Linq related items not loading

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a "task" table, which has a "sub category". The sub category is related to a Category. A category has many sub categories, but my task item only stored the sub category id (The category can be deduced from this).

So, my entity framework seems to understand this relationship.

But, my link is failing.

```
public TaskObject GetTask(int taskId)
{
    var item = (from t in _te.tasks.Include("r_sub_category").Include("r_category").Include("r_priority").Include("r_state").Include("assigned_person").Include("create_person").Include("update_person") where t.task_id == taskId select t).FirstOrDefault();
    return Transformer.UnpackTask(item);
}
```

There is a r_category table, and entity object, but when I run this, it tells me:

**A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'taskerModel.task' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'r_category'.**

And that's correct - r_category is linked to my r_sub_category table... and not directly to task. Is there a way to load the r_category?

Or, maybe this Include is lazy, and I should be doing some sort of Joining myself? Maybe more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the full path with dot Notation so im guessing it would be

```
"r_sub_category.r_category".
```

And so forth